# Catching exceptions on multiple inputs from user but not go back to first input

Tags: java, exception, input, try-catch

Here is a small program that has multiple inputs from the user to get the smallest number entered. I'm trying to catch the InputMismatchException all in the same try/catch block but if the user inputs anything but an int on say the second or third int to be entered then it jumps back to the first input which the user already entered correctly. Is there a simpler way to fix this or do I need to create separate try/catch blocks for each input?

```
    public class GrabbingSmallestValueEntered {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean correctInput = true;
            double a = 0;
            double b = 0;
            double c = 0;
        
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
                do {
                    
                    try {
                    
                    System.out.println("Input the first number: ");
                        a = input.nextDouble();
                        
                    System.out.println("Input the second number: ");
                        b = input.nextDouble();
                        
                    System.out.println("Input the third number: ");
                        c = input.nextDouble();
                        correctInput = false;
                    
                }catch (InputMismatchException ie) {
                    System.out.println("Only numbers allowed to be entered. No letters or words!");
                    input.nextLine();
                }
    
                
            } while (correctInput);
            
                System.out.println("The smallest value is " + smallest(a, b, c) + "\n");
                
}

public static double smallest(double a, double b, double c)
{ 

  return Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);
}
```

Comment: Separate try-catch seems to be a good solution here

Comment: If you go on to be a professional coder, you aren't likely to deal with problems like this. Using Scanner on the command line is mostly just for practice. I am a big proponent of "fast fail" where you give up on what you are doing early, and show the user a good error message (or log it to a file). There are some kinds of Exceptions you can recover from, but a lot of times bad input (if you can't ask the user to re-enter) is fatal

Comment: And honestly, HTML 5 is IMO the source for the best way to deal with bad user input. The INPUT tag has really useful functionality for setting attributes to define what is permissible (checked when the FORM is submitted). This is really the state of the art at the end of 2021. It's much harder to do in Java / with try { } catch

Comment: This is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Make methods. You have a task: 'ask for a double, and if the user doesn't enter one, tell them, and keep asking until they do'. You want to run this task repeatedly and with different prompts.

Parameterize the differences and make a method. Then invoke that:

```
public static double askDouble(Scanner input, String prompt) {
  while (true) {
    try {
      System.out.println(prompt);
      return input.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Only numbers allowed, etc...");
      input.next(); //don't mix nextLine and nextAnything else.
    }
  }
}
```

and then call that method in your main (no need for a do/while loop there, at all, or that `correctInput` boolean. In fact, your mine now becomes 3 very very simple lines. Yay methods!)

Comment: This is something that works but I start having issues with my variables because each input was originally a variable on its own. I created separate methods for each variable but that doesn't work because the Scanner input parameter that I created in my smallest()method is using double. And I get compiler errors in my askDouble() method in my main class. I've tried different things and just a little clarification. So need a little assistance. TYIA!

Comment: You'd just do `double a = askDouble(scanner, "Enter the first number:");` - you do not want, or need, a separate variant of `askDouble` for each question you care to ask. Follow a basic java tutorial - SO is not a handholding kind of forum. I can't help you without a paste of the exact code you have and the error you have (and such a question probably isn't appropriate for SO).

Comment: To my understanding SO is forum for people who want to learn and that need help when they come to a road block. The simple fact that you belittle peoples answers or questions is confusing to me. If that's what you're looking to do then SO isn't a forum for you!

Comment: I gave you the right answer, that's 'belittling'? There are various resources available on-site about what SO is for.

Comment: I didn't think it was appropriate for you to state that "SO is not a handholding kind of forum" to me. I'm 2 months in to learning Java. So yeah I have a lot of questions and I'm trying to fill the gap where I need help! But thank you for your assistance anyways it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array of double, read the values in a loop, in the loop you try/catch the exception. In case there is no error you increment the index.
It could be something like this :

```
double[] a = [0,0,0];
int i = 0;
do {
   try {
       System.out.println("Input the first number: ");
       a[i] = input.nextDouble();
       i++;
   } catch (InputMismatchException ie) {
        System.out.println("Only numbers allowed to be entered. No letters or words!");
        input.nextLine();
    }
} while(i<3);
```

I don't have a compiler to test this, if there is an error let me know i'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in this way...

```
package multipleinputs;
import java.util.*;

public class multipleinputs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (true) {
            try {           
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                 {
                    System.out.println("Enter integer value #" + (i + 1));
                    int num = input.nextInt();
                    if (num > max){ 
                        max = num;
                    }
                }
                break;  
            }     
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Only integer values are allowed. Try Again...");    
            } 
         }
       } 
        System.out.println("Maximum input value is " + max);
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a simpler way to fix this or do I need to create separate try/catch blocks for each input?

Yes. Instead of reading out using `nextDouble()`, just do ...

```
var input1Correct = false 
while(!input1Correct) {
  System.out.println("Input the first number: ");
  a = input.nextLine();
  input1Correct = validateInput(1)  
}
```

Then you do manual parsing and validation and if everything is OK, proceed to the next step. Otherwise, ask to reenter.

You won't even need the `catch` clause in this case.

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: This does not, at all, solve the problem of re-asking for input if the provided input isn't properly formatted. Also, indicating that an answer solves a problem is done on SO by being accepted. Don't invent your own systems for handling the concept of 'hey that works'.

Comment: See this line "Then you do manual parsing and validation and if everything is OK"

Comment: Did you create this in JS? Because var isn't even a keyword for Java. Just curious..

Comment: @Kiznet007 You are just using a lower version. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/05/25/simplify-local-variable-type-definition-using-the-java-10-var-keyword#:~:text=In%20Java%2010%2C%20the%20var,t%20need%20to%20declare%20that.&text=Each%20statement%20containing%20the%20var,the%20declared%20type%20of%20value.

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich You're absolutely right! Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: @Kiznet007 Any time, bro ;)